# docker with shared folder d drive

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-compose

I'm trying to get docker to mount my d drive. 
Have been struggling with a lot of stack and git, and none of them seem to work for me.

I already added my d drive to the shared folder

[image]

then I mount in my docker-compose.yml

[image]

running docker-compose up works when the folder is in C drive, but not when in D drive.

I will get the error package.json not found, meaning that the D drive is not mounted.

I tried to inspect my container, and this is what I get

[image]

can see that source is the right path, but it doesn't work.

Is it something wrong with my setting, or that docker doesn't support this yet? 
Any workaround? like move everything to D drive?

I did tried with setting the MACHINE_STORAGE_PATH in environment, turn out didn't work and screw up everything. Must be I did something wrong.

Please help. My new laptop only have 128GB in C drive, is not possible have everything in the C drive.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could check "[Docker: Permanently Mount a VirtualBox Shared Folder](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/2016/03/05/docker-permanently-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder/)"

Creating a shared folder in VirtualBox (which you did) is only the first step

[image: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dvm-public-assets/images/2016/03_05/virtual-box-shared-folders.png]

You still need to mount it permanently in your boot2docker ssh session:

```
sudo touch /mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh
```

Add to that file:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/src
mount -t vboxsf -o defaults,uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`id -g docker` src /mnt/src
```

Comment: tried, mounted successfully, but still not working. Still the same output.

Comment: @NinjoeQuah Can you do an `ls /mnt/d/Users/projects` and see if the folder exists and is readable?

Comment: I mounted my `d/Users` to `/mnt/src`, and I tried your suggestion `ls /mnt/src/projects` 
it did print out the files in the directory

Comment: @NinjoeQuah Did you change your volume definition in your docker-compose.yml? What does the new docker inspect shows for that container?

Comment: do I need to change anything in my docker-compose.yml? everything still the same, including the what the inspect shows.

Comment: @NinjoeQuah If you have mounted `d/Users` to `/mnt/src`, then you need to modify your `docker-compose.yml` to use `/mnt/src` for your volume.

Comment: like this? .`- :/mnt/src` and `- /mnt/src/node_modules` ?

Comment: @Nin yes, un order to use the same mapping path

Comment: tested, it works, but there's another problem with it. Which the files doesn't seems to be sync.

Comment: @NinjoeQuah Strange: those files should be in sync.

Comment: erm.. well it wasn't. retried, still the same result.

Comment: @NinjoeQuah Do you have the Guest addition installed on your VirtualBox (http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.16/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.16.iso)