# Can't mount Windows host directory to Docker container

Tags: windows, docker, mount

I'm on Windows 10 Pro with Docker Version 1.12.0-rc3-beta18 (build: 5226). I would like use Docker for PHP development on Windows machine. I tried all possible (I hope) variations of mounting host directory into Docker container:

- //c/Users/...
- /c/Users/...
- //C/Users/...
- /c/Users/...
- c:/Users/...
- c:\Users...
- "c:\Users..."
  Neither of variants launch container. Yes, `docker run` creates container and I can see it with `docker ps --all`. But I can't it start. E.g. I tried simple documentation example:

`docker run -d -P -v "C:\temp":/opt/webapp training/webapp python app.py`

and

`docker logs e030ba0f7807`

replays as

`python: can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

What happened?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using docker with docker-machine, you would need to register `c:\temp` first as a shared folder in VirtualBox.

See "[docker with shared folder d drive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38048491/6309)"

From within a `docker-machine ssh` session:

```
sudo touch /mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh
```

Add to that file:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/temp
mount -t vboxsf -o defaults,uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`id -g docker` temp /mnt/temp
```

That path would then be accessible through `/mnt/temp` for instance.

The same applies for `C:\Users`, which is already a shared folder `c/Users`.

It is accessible with `/c/Users`.

---

With Hyper-V, see "[Running Docker on Hyper-V](http://www.henning.ms/2015/05/11/running-docker-on-hyper-v/#attachment_5161)" from [Henning M Stephansen](https://twitter.com/henningmosand):

> Hyper-V is a more isolated and restrictive environment than VMWare or VirtualBox is, so there’s no concept of shared folders.
>   However we can mount and access Windows shares from our Docker VM.
>
> The first thing you need to do is to share a folder. This folder can be restricted to just your user.
>   If the VM has access to the network through an External Virtual Switch or an Internal Virtual Switch you should be able to mount your folder from the docker VM.

[image: http://www.henning.ms/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/share-internet.jpg]

> To be able to mount a windows share from Boot2Docker/Tiny Core Linux we need to install some additional module (This might be included in your image):

```
wget http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/5.x/x86/tcz/cifs-utils.tcz
tce-load -i cifs-utils.tcz
```

> Now we can mount the shared folder using the following command

```
sudo mount -t cifs //HOST-IP-HERE/SharedFolderPath /path/where/we/want/it/mounted -o username=HOST_USERNAME_HERE
```

Comment: Thanks, @Vonc, for reply! But it looks like Docker just wipes out existing container folder and replaces it with Windows host directory content. I just managed to successfully mount Windows directory with command like this: `docker run -d -P -v "D:\Users\erop\Documents\docker\index":/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs bitnami/apache` and my browser being directed to http://docker:32796/ displays index.html located in Windows directory.

Comment: @erop Docker does not just wipes out existing container folder and replaces it with Windows host directory content.

Comment: @erop See https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume. In your case, you can mount any content of /c/Users/... to any container path.

Comment: @erop That applies only to C:\Users. For Any other C:\path or D:\ (which you did not mention in your question), see my answer: shared folder, plus vboxsf in the `bootlocal.sh` of the docker-machine vm.

Comment: @erop That is, *if* you are using docker-machine, and not Hyper-V.

Comment: As I started playing with Docker I read in the documentation that I would need Hyper-V feature enabled and I enabled it before installing Docker.

Comment: @erop Best to stick with docker-machine for now. Hyper-V is still a bit young.

Comment: @erop I have added the process for Hyper-V