# docker is not allowing to mount a directory into a drupal container

Tags: drupal, docker, windows-10

I am doing something very simple puting drupal in a docker container

```
volumes: 
  - /c/Users/mark/drupalb/sites/all/modules:/var/www/html/sites/all/modules
```

this directive which should mount home directory of my modules into the containers module directory doesnt work this seems like thing that people do everyday but how to resolves this

Comment: What do you mean by "not allowing" - what errors do you get? What does `docker inspect ...` show you? Need some more debugging info to help you.

Comment: "Mounts": [
            {
                "Source": "/c/Users/mark/drupalb/sites/all/modules",
                "Destination": "/var/www/html/sites/all/modules",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"

Comment: I tried wuthout the ":z" no effect

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what your problem is. In the meantime here's a working drupal example

## Example

The folowing [compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) file

```
└── docker-compose.yml
```

Runs two containers, one for drupal the other for the db:

```
$ docker volume create --name drupal_sites
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker-compose ps
       Name                     Command             State          Ports         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dockercompose_db_1    docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up      3306/tcp             
dockercompose_web_1   apache2-foreground            Up      0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp
```

Note how the volume used to store the drupal sites is created separately, defaults to local storage but can be [something more exotic](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins/) to fit your needs

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=letmein
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal
      - MYSQL_USER=drupal
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=drupal
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
  web:
    image: drupal
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - drupal_sites:/var/www/html/sites
      - /var/www/private
volumes:
  drupal_sites:
    external: true
```

Comment: hi I want to accomplish mounting my local drupal setup on top docker drupal setup doing so taking my local edits and transposing them on a docker so for example if there are three developers working on local machine sites/all/modules which can go into drupal container not the other way around

Comment: this came in very useful from another stackoverflow user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261392/cant-mount-windows-host-directory-to-docker-container?rq=1                                                                     docker run -d -P -v "D:\Users\erop\Documents\docker\index":/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs bitnami/apache   except in my situation it just mounted the directories without any content to them so it is some sort permission from windows and yes I made my /c/Users/mark/drupalb shareable

Comment: i think i just solved my problems i ran in powershell as sugested  by https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12673 mlapierre it worked flowlesly