# Unable to mount a folder on C Drive as Volume

Tags: docker

I created a sample express site on in my User Directory and mounted it to a Docker Container and it works. Please see the output below:

```
xxxxx@DESKTOP-PCAAQU0 MINGW64 ~/ExpressSite
$ docker run -p 8080:3000 -v $(pwd):/var/www1 -w "/var/www1" node npm start
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.8
npm info using node@v7.0.0
npm info lifecycle ExpressSite@0.0.0~prestart: ExpressSite@0.0.0
npm info lifecycle ExpressSite@0.0.0~start: ExpressSite@0.0.0

> ExpressSite@0.0.0 start /var/www1
> node ./bin/www
```

If I copy/paste the same directory inside a folder called dockertest on C Drive, it get below error:

```
xxxxx@DESKTOP-PCAAQU0 MINGW64 /c/dockertest/ExpressSite
$ docker run -p 8080:3000 -v $(pwd):/var/www1 -w "/var/www1" node npm start
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.8
npm info using node@v7.0.0
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.27-boot2docker
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path /var/www1/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www1/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www1/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www1/npm-debug.log
```

Am I missing something here?

---

```
xxxxx@DESKTOP-PCAAQU0 MINGW64 /c/dockertest/ExpressSite
$ ls
app.js  bin/  node_modules/  package.json  public/  routes/  views/
```

Comment: Could not get what difference was done in second case?

Comment: Location of ExpressSite folder. In first run command, it is on my home directory and in the second one it is on C:\dockertest

Comment: Does that folder contain `package.json` ? Are you running the command from inside of that folder? `npm-debug.log` is being created runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) (requires 64bit Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise and Education (1511 November update, Build 10586 or later) and Microsoft Hyper-V), and not the old [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/) (which uses Oracle Virtual Box instead of Hyper-V.)

- Virtual Box only auto-mounted `C:\users\<yourLogin>`, and not the all C drive ([you can share other folders, but it isn't trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38048491/6309))
- Hyper-V can mount drives:

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7180398/18270828/3b385b82-742f-11e6-8c74-eb55d73b0b0a.png]

> I used the little whale icon in the taskbar to go to a settings/shared drives screen.
>   I checked off the `C` drive and clicked `Apply`. It made me enter my windows credentials.
>   I reset docker from the Settings menu after this change.

See [issue 18756](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18756) for more.
For instance, this [comment mentions](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18756#issuecomment-245247893):

> For a mingw bash shell, this is what docker toolbox adds (for example in bashrc) to stop mingw from corrupting the paths:

```
docker () {
  MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 docker.exe "$@"
}
export -f docker
```

Maybe this is not present in the bashrc of a bash session when used with Docker for Windows.